# LyX - Hiding inserted latex commands

Tags: lyx

I'm new to LyX. I needed to find an easy way for my boss to be able to edit my reports without the need to learn LaTeX. I found LyX and I think it's the solution.

Even in LyX, often times I need to use `Ctrl + L` and add some LaTeX commands.

Is there anyway to hide my LaTeX codes inside a LyX document?

I need to have those commands, however, on the other hand, I don't want them to cause confusion for my boss. I also want those commands to remain untouched at all times.

Thanks very much for your help,

Comment: So your setup is: Both have LyX installed and you share your `.lyx` file? Of course, hiding ERTs might make some of the contents confusion.

Comment: You can *partially* hide the ERT commands: right click on the ERT, and then choose `Close Inset`.

Comment: @KevinC has good advice. Also note that `ctrl + i` is a shortcut to close the inset. You can hide the latex more by writing your custom LyX styles. This is not as hard as it sounds, but takes time to learn. See Help > Customization.

Comment: @scottkosty: Thanks for the comment. I didn't realize there's a shortcut for close inset `:)`

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and for your warm welcome. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

One partial method is using `Close inset` as sugggested in the comments of your question.

Here's an ad-hoc add-on: Edit the preferences in your boss' LyX installation to make the closed ERT insets invisible.

In particular, go to `Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Colors` and change the color of `LaTeX text` to be the same as `background`, and do the same for `button background` (for collapsed inset) and for the border of the closed inset (which I couldn't find fast).

This way, the ERT will be invisible, but not locked.

If your boss should happen to click on one of those now invisible fields, her frustration might wreck your code. Not optimal, but at least the code won't show :)